# Generator.next is not a function

Tags: javascript, generator, webdriver-io

Can someone please tell me why i get the error : generator.next is not a function
i'am using webdriverIO framework and try to count the number of visible elements which correspond to some classes.

```
const generator = function* (){
            yield  $$('.class1')
            yield  $$('.class2')
            yield  $$('.class3')
            yield  $$('.class4')
            return "Done"
            }
            var N=0; 
            const  getElementObject=null;
            do {
                getElementObject = generator.next()
                for (let i =0;i< getElementObject.value.length; i++)
                     {
                         if (getElementObject.value.isVisible()==true)
                                      N++
                     }
              }while (getElementObject.value=="Done");
```

Comment: Your `generator` variable doesn't hold an iterable generator object, but a generator function.

Comment: Also, why use such a complicated looping style? Just `for (const collection of generator()) for (const element of collection) if (element.isVisible()) N++;`

Answer (score 0):

You can only call `.next()` on an iterator.

```js
async function* generator(){}

generator.next() // generator.next is not a function

const iterator = generator()

iterator.next() // ok
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys for the solutions it worked so.

```
const generator = function* (){
        yield  $$('.class1')
        yield  $$('.class2')
        yield  $$('.class3')
        yield  $$('.class4')
        }
        let N=0; 
        for (let collection of generator())
            for (let element of collection)
                     if (element.isDisplayed()==true)
                                  N++
          console.log(`theResultIs ${chalk.green(N)}`)
```